# Items get re-added in checkbox while scrolling in recycler view android

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a list of items in a RecyclerView containing checkboxes, I am trying to get selected items in a checkbox from my `adapter` to my `fragment`.

**Problem**

The item gets reAdded every time I scroll to the position of the item.

E.g. -

When I check an item, it gets added to my list of selected items - Fine.
But when I scroll down and scroll up, the item gets added again. The same thing happens over and over again while scrolling.

**Adapter**

```
var checkedSongs = ArrayList<Songs>()
var checkBoxStateArray = SparseBooleanArray()
inner class SelectSongsViewHolder(val binding: RcvLytSelectSongsBinding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    binding.root)
 {
   init {
     binding.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
     if (isChecked){
        val song = songs[absoluteAdapterPosition]
        checkedSongs.add(song)
       }
       else{
       val song = songs[absoluteAdapterPosition]
       checkedSongs.remove(song)
            }
       checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, isChecked)
      }
    }
}

.......
//In onBindViewHolder
binding.checkbox.isChecked = checkBoxStateArray.get(position, false)

//Function to get all checked songs
fun getSelectedSongs(): ArrayList<Songs> {
    return checkedSongs
}
```

**Fragment**

```
binding.txtDone.setOnClickListener {
 val selectedRows = selectSongsAdapter.getSelectedSongs()
 Toast.makeText(requireContext(), selectedRows.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

So lets say I have 5 items in the list

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.

When I check item 1, and click done...**Toast message = "[Item(item1)]"**

When I scroll down and scroll up.....**Toast message = "[Item(item1), Item(item1)]"**

...It goes on and on like that.

Comment: You can disable the recycling process by adding this line below recyler's set layout manager.. `recyclerView.recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(0,0)`

Comment: This will defeat the purpose of recyclerview and the checkbox isn't recycling per say. It is the selected item that gets duplicated on scroll

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your ArrayList contains that object or not. Since you're using Kotlin, if your `Songs` model class contains any unique identifier for each song like an objectId or something, you can use something simple like a predicate:

```
    val checkSongExist = checkedSongs.any { it.id == song.id }
    if (!checkSongExist) {
        // write your code here to add items to array
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns an empty list...nothing is been added.

if (isChecked){
                    val song = songs[absoluteAdapterPosition]
                    checkedSongs.find { listItem ->
                        if (listItem.mediaId != song.mediaId) {
                            checkedSongs.add(song)
                        } else {
                            false
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: You can remove the conditions and only check if the song ID exists in that list, and if returns an empty list, that means the song isn't there and you can add it afterward using your code. Similarly, if you don't get an empty list, it means the song exists, in that case, just don't add the song. That should work.

Comment: Please can you modify your answer(code) to this regards, thanks

Comment: Unresolved reference: "!"

Cant use the ! (Not Equal operator there)

Comment: Check the latest edit, use `any`, it'll give you a Boolean as per if your predicate matches or not. And you can use a simple if-condition.

Comment: Still returns an empty list from the fragment.

When I use a Toast, it displays "{}" meaning empty list even if items were checked in the adapter